# Export data to cells in existing excel file

Tags: c#, excel, file, export

How can I export values from windows form textboxes into existing excel file?
There are 4 values (strings) that I´d like to be sent to an existing excel file when a "export" button is clicked. The exportbutton is in another class.

when the Exportbutton is clicked i want the 4 below values inputed by me or the user to be sent in the existing excel file´s 2nd sheet (there are 3). Ideally I´d like to choose what cells the 4 values are to be sent to.

```
namespace XLSdataexport
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
      public Form1()
      {
          InitializeComponent();
      }


      public string temp;
      public string humidity;
      public string pressure;
      public string alfa;

      private void textBox1_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          temp = textBox1.Text;
      }
      private void textBox2_textChanged_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          humid = textBox2.Text;

      }
      private void textBox3_textChanged_3(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          press = textBox3.Text;

      }
      private void textBox4_textChanged_4(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          alfa = textBox4.Text;

      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Did you even try to [google this](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+Export+data+to+cells+in+existing+excel+file&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b)? You are supposed to show some research effort, not meaningless events.

Comment: Thanks RH6. Yes the other thread had an answer. Pardon my miss.
And as for you TaW 2. Your reply was´nt exactly helpful. You might as well have skipped commenting.

Answer (score 0):

To export data to Excel, you can use the ClosedXML.Report library (https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML.Report). Believe me, this is a wonderful library and easy for her to use. The library does not need Excel Interop. ClosedXML.Report generates an Excel file based on a template that you can create in Excel using any formatting. For example:

```
        var template = new XLTemplate(@".\Templates\template.xlsx");

        Form1 dataForm = ...
        template.AddVariable("temp", dataForm.temp);
        template.AddVariable("humidity", dataForm.humidity);
        template.AddVariable("pressure", dataForm.pressure);
        template.AddVariable("alfa", dataForm.alfa);
        template.Generate();

        template.SaveAs(@".\Output\card.xlsx");
```

And use XLSX-template like this:

[image]